# Can I extend App Engine Standard error JSON in Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, error-handling, servlet-filters

App Engine manages what's returned as error JSON on Cloud Endpoints. When I throw `ServiceException` which Google supplies, I pass it `statusCode` and `statusMessage`:

```
public ServiceException(int statusCode, String statusMessage) {
    super(statusMessage);

    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.reason = null;
    this.domain = null;
}
```

App Engine then returns this JSON to the caller in the error response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required",
                "message": "The statusMessage I gave it."
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "The statusMessage I gave it."
    }
}
```

I would like to extend the response with an extra field, e.g. for an application error code which tells the client what went wrong (message should be human readable).

I'm not so deep into Java servlets and internal workings of this, but I have tried to catch the response and modify it, which worked for a 200 response, but not for an error response. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are requesting, I would suggest you take a look at how the ServiceException class works on the Java [endpoints-framework](https://github.com/cloudendpoints/endpoints-java/blob/master/endpoints-framework/src/main/java/com/google/api/server/spi/ServiceException.java).

Here you can check how the exceptions are being handled and, based on this, extend the error JSON that is returned to suit your needs, that is, that anyone can understand why his run failed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this class, but it won't help much as this class doesn't produce the JSON: It's GAE which keeps processing contents of that class to JSON and that seems hidden to me.

Comment: I suppose you want the JSON to come from App Engine with the custom message you are suggesting, am I correct?

Have you considered creating your own [custom service exception class](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/exceptions#creating_your_own_exception_classes) that extends the one I put in my answer? There you can also check which error codes are currently supported by App Engine.

If this still doesn't work for you, you can always try and file a feature request so the Google team can add that functionality for everyone to use.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo, I have tried to extend that class. I'll file a feature request.